# Apache Spark timing forEach operation on JavaRDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, timing, accumulator

**Question: Is this a valid way to test the time taken to build a RDD?**

I am doing two things here. The basic approach is that we have M instances of what we call a DropEvaluation, and N DropResults. We need to compare each N DropResult to each of M DropEvaluations. Each N must be seen by each M, to give us M results in the end.

If I don't use the .count() once the RDD is built, the driver continues on to the next line of code and says it look almost no time to build a RDD that takes 30 minutes to build.

**I just want to make sure I am not missing something, like maybe the .count() taking a long time? I guess to time the .count() I'd have to modify Spark's source?**

M = 1000 or 2000. N = 10^7.

It's effectively a cartesian problem -- the accumulator was chosen because we need to write to each M in place. I would also be ugly to build the full cartesian RDD.

We build a List of M Accumulators (can't do a List Accumulator in Java right?). Then we loop through each of N in a RDD with a foreach.

**Clarifying the Question: The total time taken is measured correctly, I am asking if the .count() on the RDD forces Spark to wait until the RDD is finished before it can run a count. Is the .count() time significant?**

Here's our code:

```
// assume standin exists and does it's thing correctly

// this controls the final size of RDD, as we are not parallelizing something with an existing length
List<Integer> rangeN = IntStream.rangeClosed(simsLeft - blockSize + 1, simsLeft).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

// setup bogus array of size N for parallelize dataSetN to lead to dropResultsN       
JavaRDD<Integer> dataSetN = context.parallelize(rangeN);

// setup timing to create N
long NCreationStartTime = System.nanoTime();

// this maps each integer element of RDD dataSetN to a "geneDropped" chromosome simulation, we need N of these:
JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.map(s -> standin.call(s)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

// **** this line makes the driver wait until the RDD is done, right?
long dummyLength = dropResultsN.count();


long NCreationNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime() - NCreationStartTime;
double NCreationSeconds = (double)NCreationNanoSeconds / 1000000000.0;
double NCreationMinutes = NCreationSeconds / 60.0;

logger.error("{} test sims remaining", simsLeft);

// now get the time for just the dropComparison (part of accumulable's add)
long startDropCompareTime = System.nanoTime();

// here we iterate through each accumulator in the list and compare all N elements of dropResultsN RDD to each M in turn, our .add() is a custom AccumulableParam
for (Accumulable<TholdDropTuple, TholdDropResult> dropEvalAccum : accumList) {
    dropResultsN.foreach(new VoidFunction<TholdDropResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(TholdDropResult dropResultFromN) throws Exception {
                            dropEvalAccum.add(dropResultFromN);
                    }
                });
            }

    // all the dropComparisons for all N to all M for this blocksize are done, check the time...
   long dropCompareNanoSeconds = System.nanoTime() - startDropCompareTime;
   double dropCompareSeconds = (double)dropCompareNanoSeconds / 1000000000.0;
    double dropCompareMinutes = dropCompareSeconds / 60.0;

    // write lines to indicate timing section
    // log and write to file the time for the N-creation

    ...

} // end for that goes through dropAccumList
```

Comment: I would note in response to Dikei's answer below, which I +1'd, it doesn't answer the core issue, is this a valid way to exactly time the creation of an RDD? Does the count take a significant time in itself, that it bloats the RDD creation time? Any links to good examples of timing Spark things?

Answer (score 1):

Spark program is lazy, it will not run until you call all action like `count` on the RDD. You can find a list of common action in [Spark's document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions)

```
// **** this line makes the driver wait until the RDD is done, right?
long dummyLength = dropResultsN.count();
```

Yes, in this case `count` force the `dropResultsN` to be computed, so it'll take a long time. If you do a second `count`, it'll return very fast since the RDD is already computed and cached.

Comment: If the RDD were never computed I would agree with you. Since I do call `dropResultsN.foreach` this causes it to be computed. Foreach is in the list you linked. So half-wrong, I think? Also I thought I cached it thus: `JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.map(s -> standin.call(s)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());` ... or am I only persisting dataSetN? wow you may have just blown my mind :)

Comment: My mistake, I did not see the `persist` call. Calling `persist` with MEMORY_ONLY is the same as calling `cache`.

Comment: See comment above on my question, you do hit on the idea that the first .count() takes a long time, if you had some other observations about valid approaches to timing Spark or some links/examples, I might accept this answer, otherwise gonna let it go a few days and see who chimes in. Thanks.

Comment: No, I found from this other question (in my own answer) that I was persisting the right thing. All the same, it's better to follow the example given in [my answer from an O'Reilly book, Learning Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317733/apache-spark-what-am-i-persisting-here/38317865#38317865): `rddToPersist = existingRDD.map.etc.etc; rddToPersist.persist();`