# Apache Spark what am I persisting here?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, timing

In this line, which RDD is being persisted? dropResultsN or dataSetN?

```
dropResultsN = dataSetN.map(s -> standin.call(s)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Question arises as a side issue from [Apache Spark timing forEach operation on JavaRDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296950/apache-spark-timing-foreach-operation-on-javardd), where I am still looking for a good answer to the core question of how best to time RDD creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropResultsN` is the persisted RDD (which is the RDD produced by mapping `dataSetN` onto the method `standin.call()`).

Comment: That's also what I would have thought, and when I take the call away Spark (insanely) keeps recomputing the RDD, even though it should be included in the DAG of tasks to be run in this application. It would be nice if your answer included a link to something and quoted that something. Without digging into the source code, which I'll do next.

Comment: NVM previous comment I found a good example in Learning Spark and posted a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example of this in Learning Spark by O'Reilly:

It's example 3-40. persist() in Scala (assuming Java is the same)

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

val result = input.map( x => x*x )
result.persist(StorageLevel.[<your choice>][1])
```

> NOTE in Learning Spark: Notice that we called persist() on the RDD
>   before the first action. The persist() call on its own doesn't force
>   evaluation.

MY NOTE that in this example the persist is on the next line, I think this is much more clear than my code in my question.